# Why is the path written into my ui in a batch call

Tags: r, batch-file, shiny

When I start my Shiny App via batch call the path of my console is written into my ui. I dont know why.

batch.cmd

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "app.r"
```

app.r

```
runApp(folder_address, launch.browser=TRUE)
```

The output

[image]

Also there is this app.r.Rout (same text as rhistory) file that i dont want. Is there a way to get rid of that too.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Also paste the output, thanks

Comment: `R CMD BATCH` will always produce the .Rout file. Why not use `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1\bin\R.exe" -e "shiny::runApp(folder_access, launch.browser=TRUE)"` instead?

Comment: because there is some preprocessing being done in app.r. What would be the difference to your approach?